# HTML Redirect to download exe file

Tags: php, html, redirect

I want to redirect to a download exe file. In internet explorer the browser automatically questions me if I want to run or save file. In chrome gets only the save as file. How can I make to do the same in Chrome as in IE ?

Thank you

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
 $file_url = 'file://suas105/deployment/PnS_Token_WIPG-300H/WIPG-300H/WIPG-300H.exe';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Location: $url");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
?>
<!--<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=file://suas105/deployment/PnS_Token_WIPG-300H/WIPG-300H/WIPG-300H.exe" />-->
<title>Page redirection</title>
</head>
<body>
   <!--If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='file://suas105/deployment/PnS_Token_WIPG-300H/WIPG-300H/WIPG-300H.exe' download>link to example</a>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can, I'm fairly certain that chrome won't let you run exe files from the browser

Answer (score 1):

It's security issue for Chrome, that's why there is no "Run as" function. Same as Firefox. You can search for some extensions, bet you can't be sure that user will have that extension installed.

Comment: Thank you . Do you know if it's possible to redirect to IE if users are using Chrome ?

Comment: Redirect to IE? What do you mean by that?

Comment: if it uses Chrome to force them to use IE

Comment: @RalucaIonescu Use your logic. User uses Mac/Linux and Chrome. How do you redirect to IE? It's obvious that it's not possible for lots of reasons.